# Read values from buffer in C

Tags: c

I have buffer output like -

```
100
4
0,0 0,1 10
3,5 2,4 10
1,6 1,5 10
99,99 99,98 10
```

Here I want to read the value 4.

```
#include <string.h>
#define DATA_SIZE 1
#define NO_ELEMENTS 60

void 
create_fov() {

    char tbuff[4096];
    char workbuff[4096];
    char shell_command[4096];
    int row = 0 , col = 0, counter_outer = 0, prev_counter = 0, counter_to = 0;
    int fov_plane[row][col];

    strcpy(shell_command,"cat fov_plane_input.txt | grep -v '//' | grep 'Size of FOV_plane' | awk '{print $5}' \n");
    strcat(shell_command,"cat fov_plane_input.txt | grep -v '//' | grep 'Number of Nodes' | awk '{print $5}' \n");
    strcat(shell_command,"cat fov_plane_input.txt | grep -v '//' | grep '^[0-9]' \n");
//  printf("%s", shell_command);

    FILE *read_fov_params = popen(shell_command, "r");
    fread(tbuff,DATA_SIZE,NO_ELEMENTS,read_fov_params);

//      loop to extract size of fov (m and n values) from fov_plane_input.txt
    for (counter_outer = 0; counter_outer < DATA_SIZE * NO_ELEMENTS ; counter_outer ++ , counter_to++)
    {
        if (tbuff[counter_outer] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }

        workbuff[counter_to] = tbuff[counter_outer];

    }

    row = col = atoi(workbuff);
//printf("%d", atoi(workbuff));

//      loop to extract position of first camera from fov_plane_input.txt
    for (counter_outer = 0; counter_outer < DATA_SIZE * NO_ELEMENTS ; counter_outer ++ , counter_to++)
    {
        if (tbuff[counter_outer] == ',')
        {
            break;
        }

        workbuff[counter_to] = tbuff[counter_outer];

    }

printf("%s", workbuff);
```

the output of printf("%s", workbuff); is - 100100
4
0

What am I missing in my last loop ?
pls guide.

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to read value 4. So you don't need to start reading from first so **increase counter_outer** value and **reset counter_to** value and also reset workbuff buffer.

```
memset(workbuff, 0x00, 4096);
//loop to extract position of first camera from fov_plane_input.txt
for (counter_to = 0, counter_outer++; counter_outer < DATA_SIZE * NO_ELEMENTS ; counter_outer ++ , counter_to++)
{
    if (tbuff[counter_outer] == '\n')
    {
       break;
    }
    workbuff[counter_to] = tbuff[counter_outer];
}
```

Side note:

Also when you are declaring variables then try to initialize them with zero other wise you will get garbage values and output will not come as per your expectation.